# injective dimension of nilradical multiplied by an injective module

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-module

I would like to prove the following:

**Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with identity, $I$ an injective module, and $N=\sqrt{(0)}$ (the nilradical). Then $I/NI$ is an injective $R/N$ module.**

If I can show that the injective dimension of $NI$ over $R$ is less than or equal to 1 I think I know how to prove it via the short exact sequence

$0\to NI\to I\to I/NI$.

Thanks for the help.